# Validation keeps looping, won't allow for re-entering information

Tags: python, validation

I'm a Software Development student and currently working on a Python project that contains a "license plate" in the format of LLL000. This is the code I'm currently using but it does not allow the user to re-enter the information after the validation comes back false. It does display the message, though.

while True:
PlateNum = input("Enter the plate number (XXX000): ").upper()

```
if len(PlateNum) == 6:
    TestPlateOne = PlateNum[:3]
    TestPlateTwo = PlateNum[3:6]

if TestPlateOne.isdigit() == True and TestPlateTwo.isdigit() == False:
        print("The plate number must start with 3 letters and end with 3 letters. Please re-enter.")
else:
    break

if PlateNum == "":
    print("The plate number cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")
else:
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where are you getting the input for number plate in above code? the code starts with an already read PlateNum and then there are validations on there.

If before this code, you are reading the PlateNum from user, then you can put the entire code in a function, and depending on the result from function, either ask user to enter number plate again, or move ahead.

Comment: For some reason it didn't enter into the "code" area of what I've got there, but it's from an input, using while True. PlateNum = input("Enter the plate number (XXX000): ").upper()

Comment: what input are you trying it with?

Comment: I was using 000XXX

But fortunately I was able to fix the problem by removing the break from that validation, and making the second validation an elif.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by removing the break from that validation, and making the second validation an elif.

Solution: if TestPlateOne.isdigit() == True and TestPlateTwo.isdigit() == False:
print("The plate number must start with 3 letters and end with 3 letters. Please re-enter.")

elif PlateNum == "":
print("The plate number cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")
else:
break

Comment: Hello, nice that you found an answer. If it is an answer please mark it as one. For readability it would be if you could also format it with code tags. thank you